# Python/numpy - efficiency of tensor notation and normal matrices

Tags: python, matrix, tensor

I hope this question won't sound weird. I am going to write a code in Python to simulate some optical non linearities in waveguides and I was wondering what is the most efficient notation I can use to save time and energies. 
I come from a MatLab background where everyone tells you that matrices are way more efficient than cycles but now, most of the times, I use the tensor notation (for example, in FORTRAN, a matrix multiplication would result in something like [that](http://www.continuummechanics.org/tensornotationbasic.html):

```
subroutine aa_dot_bb(n,a,b,c)
  dimension a(n,n), b(n,n), c(n,n)
  do i = 1,n
     do j = 1,n
        c(i,j) = 0
        do k = 1,n
           c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k) * b(k,j)
        end do
     end do
  end do
  return
  end
```

Does anybody know what is more efficient in Python and NumPy? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python and numpy world, it is same as in Matlab, so as you mention, the for loops are slow, and the matrix operations expressed by native numpy operations are fast, so your goal is to vectorize all operations as you would do in matlab. Numpy behaves very much like matlab. 
If you are familiar with matlab, I recommend you [numpy for matlab users documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). But as @ntipakos mentions, it can be expressed as matrix multiplications which can be written as

```
a = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1]])
b = np.array([[4, 1],[2,2]])
y = np.matmul(a, b)
y = a @ b    # alternative notation using @ operator
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I just put that example to show what I mean with the tensor notation, because one can maybe think of proper tensors which are actually matrices. And thank you for that documentation too! I am glad they work in a similar way!

Comment: @Pan Glad I helped, if it answered your question, you can accept the answer so your question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you just ask for matrix multiplication?

```
a = np.array([[1, 0],[0,1]])
b = np.array([[4, 1],[2,2]])
y = np.matmul(a, b)
```